# Change visibility of ASP.NET controls before Reponse

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple button event handler in ASP.NET that allows the user to download a spreadsheet to their browser and at the same time displays a set of controls relating to futher processing of that spreadsheet. The code is below:

```
Protected Sub btnDownLoadReview_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownLoadReview.Click
    Dim excelEngine As ExcelEngine = New ExcelEngine()
    Dim mboXLS() As Byte = Session("ScrubDataExcel")
    Dim stream As Stream = New MemoryStream(mboXLS)
    Dim workBookFinal As IWorkbook = excelEngine.Excel.Workbooks.Open(stream)
    Dim fileName As String = UniqueFileName(".xls")
    Dim sURL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UploadFileName").ToString() & "_" & fileName

    lblDoYouWishToModify.Visible = True
    btnUploadCorrections.Visible = True
    fupSelectFile.Visible = True
    btnUploadCorrections.Visible = True
    lblYouMayResubmit.Visible = True

    workBookFinal.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(sURL))

    Response.ContentType = "application/xls"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sURL)
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(sURL))
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

The problem seems to be the presence of the Reponse object invocations. If I remove these 4 lines, the controls display. If I refer to even one of them the controls do not display. No error is thrown but it seems as if the Visible property settings are ignored.

I tried moving the Visible settings to positions before and after the Reponse settings but to no avail.

Any ideas as to what could be wrong here?

Thanks

Carl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP GridView Refresh after Excel Export not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571822/asp-gridview-refresh-after-excel-export-not-working)

Comment: You cannot export AND update the UI. It is one or the other.